# Get the column number of a search criteria in a defined range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
   A      B                  C          D       E       F      G       H    
1     Search Criteria:    Prod.D
2     Column:               4
3                                   Prod.A   Prod.B  Prod.C  Prod.D   Prod.E
4                      
5
```

In `Range D3:H4` I have `Product A` to `Product E` listed. 
Now, I want to achieve that when I put a product name into `Cell C1` I will get back the **Column Number** of the product in the range.

In the example above I want to search for `Prod.D` within the  `Range D3:H4` and therefore the result in `Cell C2` should be `4` since the search criteria appears in the fourth column within the defined range.

What formula do I need to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula in cell `C2`:

```
=MATCH(C1,D3:H3,0)
```